# Check status 1 day prior to date

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a simple table `t1` which contains `id`s and implementation (of a product) dates:

```
| id    | implementation_date |
|-------|---------------------|
| 90    | 2020-01-03          |
| 3453  | 2020-01-03          |
| 1324  | 2020-01-03          |
| 75133 | 2020-01-03          |
| 11143 | 2020-01-03          |
| 21411 | 2020-01-03          |
...
...
```

I then have a second table `t2` which is a daily log of `ids` and weather they are eligible to implement or not:

```
| id         | yyyy_mm_d  | eligible_status |
|------------|------------|-----------------|
| 90         | 2020-01-01 | 1               |
| 3453       | 2020-01-01 | 1               |
| 1324       | 2020-01-01 | 0               |
| 75133      | 2020-01-01 | 1               |
| 11143      | 2020-01-01 | 1               |
| 90         | 2020-01-02 | 1               |
| 3453       | 2020-01-02 | 1               |
| 1324       | 2020-01-02 | 0               |
| 75133      | 2020-01-02 | 1               |
| 11143      | 2020-01-02 | 1               |
...
...
```

How could I write a query which will select what the `eligible_status` was for each `id` the day prior to its `implementation_date`.

Note that not all ids in `t1` may have a row in `t2` a day before the `implementation_date`, in such cases it would be great to indicate this.

Example output:

```
| id    | implementation_date | eligible_status_day_before_implementation |
|-------|---------------------|-------------------------------------------|
| 90    | 2020-01-03          | 1                                         |
| 3453  | 2020-01-03          | 1                                         |
| 1324  | 2020-01-03          | 0                                         |
| 75133 | 2020-01-03          | 1                                         |
| 11143 | 2020-01-03          | 1                                         |
| 21411 | 2020-01-03          | no_rows_found_prior_to_implementation     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select 
    t1.id,
    t1.implementation_date,
    coalesce(t2.eligible_status, 
        "no_rows_found_prior_to_implementation")
        as eligible_status_day_before_implementation
from t1
left join t2
on to_date(t1.implementation_date) = date_add(to_date(t2.yyyy_mm_d), 1)
    and t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: The interval seems to be throwing an error - `cannot recognize input near 'interval' '1' 'day' in expression specification`

Comment: date_add does work! Though, should we not do date_add on t1.implementation_date? Since we want to see the eligible status from the day before?

Comment: @Someguywhocodes you want t2 = day before t1, i.e. t2 = t1 - 1, or t1 = t2 + 1